# Shared IP and Private IP in Same BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to have a shared IP (in it's own delivery profile) after SAP has been configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Business Unit can only have one SAP, and SAP manages a relationship to either shared or private IP address. Hence it is not possible to use both simultaneously on a single SAP. If you want to be able to use both options, you will need to use two separate Business Units.